# Deleting rows in a panda where there are less than 3 non zero values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to remove the rows that have less than 3 non-zero values (not including total column)  from my panda DataFrame.

So at the moment I have.

```
    year    2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 TOTAL
    player  
    Emma    0     0     0    0    3    4    5    12
    Max     3     5     0    0    0    0    0    8
    Josh    1     2     4    1    2    1    0    11
    Steve   0     0     0    0    3    0    0    3
    Mike    1     0     0    0    0    0    2    3
```

But I want:

```
    year    2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 TOTAL
    player  
    Emma    0     0     0    0    3    4    5    12
    Josh    1     2     4    1    2    1    0    11
```

I was thinking of using a for loop but I'm not sure how to implement it/ if it's the best way to go about solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

***`pandas`***
*I `drop` `TOTAl` and `sum` the number of non-zeros for each row*

```
df[df.drop('TOTAL', 1).ne(0).sum(1).gt(2)]

year    2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  TOTAL
player                                                 
Emma       0     0     0     0     3     4     5     12
Josh       1     2     4     1     2     1     0     11
```

***`numpy`***
*faster solution*

```
v = df.values
m = (v[:, :-1] != 0).sum(1) > 2
pd.DataFrame(v[m], df.index[m], df.columns)

year    2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  TOTAL
player                                                 
Emma       0     0     0     0     3     4     5     12
Josh       1     2     4     1     2     1     0     11
```

Comment: Thanks mate!  df[df.ne(0).sum(1) > 3] worked a treat

Comment: /ot  the bold/italic/quote is a bit cramped in my browser...  I prefer the bold/italic or if needed the bold/quote.  But an upper for working the field...

Comment: @StephenRauch So I'm clear... You're telling me that my use of bold/italic/code_quote makes your eyes bleed.  And if I want you to continue reading my answers, I ought to stop.

Comment: @StephenRauch Good to know, I'll try a more subtle formatting style :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2001': {'Emma': 0, 'Josh': 1, 'Max': 3, 'Mike': 1, 'Steve': 0},
 '2002': {'Emma': 0, 'Josh': 2, 'Max': 5, 'Mike': 0, 'Steve': 0},
 '2003': {'Emma': 0, 'Josh': 4, 'Max': 0, 'Mike': 0, 'Steve': 0},
 '2004': {'Emma': 0, 'Josh': 1, 'Max': 0, 'Mike': 0, 'Steve': 0},
 '2005': {'Emma': 3, 'Josh': 2, 'Max': 0, 'Mike': 0, 'Steve': 3},
 '2006': {'Emma': 4, 'Josh': 1, 'Max': 0, 'Mike': 0, 'Steve': 0},
 '2007': {'Emma': 5, 'Josh': 0, 'Max': 0, 'Mike': 2, 'Steve': 0},
 'TOTAL': {'Emma': 12, 'Josh': 11, 'Max': 8, 'Mike': 3, 'Steve': 3}})
```

**Solution**

```
df.loc[np.sum(df.iloc[:,:-1]>0, axis=1)[lambda x: x>=3].index]
    Out[889]: 
      2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  TOTAL
Emma     0     0     0     0     3     4     5     12
Josh     1     2     4     1     2     1     0     11
```

Alternatively use groupby and filter:

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: np.sum(x.iloc[0,:]>0)>=4)
Out[918]: 
      2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  TOTAL
Emma     0     0     0     0     3     4     5     12
Josh     1     2     4     1     2     1     0     11
```